# Сортировка с выдачей процентов категории Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть исходный DF

```
Vid1    Vid2    Res
1   4234    A
1   523 A
1   423552  A
1   625 B
1   3524    C
2   4254    A
2   4325    C
2   435 C
2   2532    B
2   5235    B
```

Необходимо для каждого Vid1 посчитать процент вхождения каждой из категорий из Res. `А` входила 3 раза из 5, то есть 0,6, `B`=0,2, `C`=0,2.
То есть на выходе необходимо получить нечто такое:

```
Vid1    resA    resB    resC
1   0,6 0,2 0,2
2   0,2 0,4 0,4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [39]: res =  (df
                 .groupby(["Vid1"])
                 ["Res"]
                 .apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).size()/len(x))
                 .unstack())

In [40]: res
Out[40]:
1       A    B    C
Vid1
1     0.6  0.2  0.2
2     0.2  0.4  0.4

In [41]: res.loc[1, "B"]
Out[41]: 0.2
```

Comment: Подскажите, как обратиться по индексу например к Vid1 - B ? Ну то есть чтобы получить на выходе числа `0.2`